# Safe way of changing views?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, subviews

We have such function in application delegate. When local notification comes the code below is executed and it may cause crash as I understand in the line where insertSubview performs.
How may I safely do that? Thanks.

```
-(void)changeController:(UIViewController*)newController {
    self.currentController = newController;
    if([self.window.subviews containsObject:self.menuController.view]) {
        [self.window insertSubview:newController.view belowSubview:self.menuController.view];
    }
    else {
        self.window.rootViewController = self.currentController;
    }
}
```

Comment: What crash are you seeing? Please provide more information about what the problem is so that we can help you solve it.

Comment: The error is that view is not exist anymore. This happens when transitioning between controllers.

Comment: @Oleg in your case, you can check whether the view exist, if no, return.

Answer (score 1):

If your views/view controllers are part of a `UINavigationViewController`, then the way you should be managing them is by using the methods of that class: specifically things like [`pushViewController:animated:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/pushViewController%3aanimated%3a). In general, if you have views that are “controlled by” their own view controllers, you should probably not be grabbing those views and attaching them to other view hierarchies.

Comment: I concur with you shouldn't do it really